# Return to top level domain with url_for()

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a page on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`, which redirects to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/results`

in my `/results` page, I want to include a link that will return me to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`. I've tried various things using `url_for()`:

```
<h2>Or search <a href="{{ url_for(filename='/') }}">something else</a></h2>
<h2>Or search <a href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/') }}">something else</a></h2>
```

However these throw errors such as `TypeError: url_for() missing 1 required positional argument: 'endpoint'`

(keep in mind I can't just do `href="http://127.0.0.1:5000"` because the url might change, and I don't want to have to change it manually

How can I do that? (sorry for noob question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i've figured it out. It's named after the function that was assigned to it.  e.g. if top level was:

```
@app.route('/')
def search():
    return render_template('landing.html')
```

Then `url_for("search")` would work (as it's not a standard url)